# New User Registration take long time (more than 60 seconds)

Tags: 6, users

New user registration take too much time in my drupal 6 website. When we perform **Add user** in administrator section, it is working normally, within one or two second we can add users. But when we are trying to **Create new account**, it takes long time.

I have enabled CCK, Content Profile,Token,CAPTCHA,Views Modules.

How does debug it ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the devel module and see which part of Drupal that slows things down. You could start out by taking a look at the queries that are run.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to debug the code to see where in the code Drupal gets slow. [Here](http://dharmatech.org/ideas/2010/using-xdebug-find-slow-code-drupal) is a great tutorial how to track the slow parts down.

An other thing you should test is give a normal user the privilege to create users (`Administer users`). See if it works as slow as `Create new account`. What actions are done when creating the new account by the way?

Comment: I assigned new user to privilege Create Users (`Administer users`).But while `Create new account` its extremely fast, and when logout and doing the `Create new account` its too slow. why this happen ?